# How do I write the time from datetime to a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I'm trying to have my Python code write everything it does to a log, with a timestamp. But it doesn't seem to work.

this is my current code:

```
filePath= Path('.')
time=datetime.datetime.now()
bot_log = ["","Set up the file path thingy"]
with open ('bot.log', 'a') as f:
  f.write('\n'.join(bot_log)%
  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)"))
  print(bot_log[0])
```

but when I run it it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Name\Yuna-Discord-Bot\Yuna Discord Bot.py", line 15, in <module>
    f.write('\n'.join(bot_log)%
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I have tried multiple things to fix it, and this is the latest one. is there something I'm doing wrong or missing? I also want the time to be in front of the log message, but I don't think it would do that (if it worked).

Comment: Did you try to check what is happening on that line of code? For example, where the code says `'\n'.join(bot_log)`, what do you expect to be the result? Did you try to check what the result is? Did it meet your expectation? Now, *does it make sense to have that on the left-hand side of `%`*? Why or why not? What do you think the `%` means here? Do you actually understand, step by step, what you intend for this line of code to do? Or are you trying to copy code from somewhere else and change things until it works for your situation?

Comment: "I have tried multiple things to fix it, and this is the latest one." We can only possibly help with the things that you show us, not with things you mention in passing. Please read [ask] and [mre], and show the thought process behind the code.

Comment: Can you please clarify what output you expect? Using `%` there doesn't make much sense, so it's hard to say what you want. Did you intend to use `+` perhaps?

Comment: Note that as for "write everything it does to a log, with a timestamp", that's what `logging` is there for. This is a task many people face, there is no need to reinvent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put "%s" somewhere in the input string before string formatting. [Here's more detailed explanation.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-s-mean-in-a-python-format-string/)

Try this:

```
filePath= Path('.')
time=datetime.datetime.now()
bot_log = "%s Set up the file path thingy\n"
with open ('bot.log', 'a') as f:
  f.write(bot_log % datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)"))
  print(bot_log)
```

Comment: It works, but it prints the time and the action on separate lines. However, I want the time and the action to be both on the same line. Is that possible?

Comment: just do this bot_log = ["","%s Set up the file path thingy"]

Comment: I'll update the code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to write three strings to your file as separate lines. I've rearranged your code to create a single list to pass to `writelines`, which expects an iterable:

```
filePath= Path('.')
time=datetime.datetime.now()
bot_log = ["","Set up the file path thingy"]
with open ('bot.log', 'a') as f:
    bot_log.append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)"))
    f.writelines('\n'.join(bot_log))
    print(bot_log[0])
```

EDIT: From the comments the desire is to prepend the timestamp to the message and keep it on the same line. I've used [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) as I prefer the clarity they provide:

```
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

filePath = Path('.')

with open('bot.log', 'a') as f:
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    msg = "Set up the file path thingy"
    f.write(f"""{time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")} {msg}\n""")
```

You could also look at the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#basic-logging-tutorial) which does a lot of this for you.

Comment: This works, however, I want the time and the message on the same line. And if possible also the time before the message.